# find specific words in text files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, find

I have many text files in different sub directories, whereby each files has the file extension ".pro".

Each file contains of one or more lines where the text "PRO `<name>`," or "Function `<name>`," occurs. 
After the `<name>` follows a comma followed by variables.

I would like to generate a list consisting of 2 columns:

- 1st column: the full file name (with full path)
- 2nd column: "PRO `<name>`" or/and "Function `<name>`

For the two example files/scripts below the resulting text would be:

```
<full path>read_scenes_out.pro  PRO READ_SCENES_CLA
<full path>read_scenes_out.pro  PRO PRO READ_TAU_IN
<full path>read_scenes_out.pro  FUNCTION READ_HRIT
<full path>read_scenes_in.pro   PRO READ_SCENES_FLG
<full path>read_scenes_in.pro   PRO READ_SCENES_ELEV
<full path>read_scenes_in.pro   PRO READ_TAU_IN
<full path>read_scenes_in.pro   FUNCTION READ_HRIT2
```

Since I am a beginner with Linux I cannot solve this myself. The only small success was two find out how to list all full path's of pro files in all subdirectories:

find . | grep ".pro" | sort -z

May be this can be combined with [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-with-the-comma).

---

Two example files ("..." is a place holder for programming code):

- file name 1 named "read_scenes_out.pro"

  PRO READ_SCENES_CLA, ICLA, INDATE=INDATE

  ...

  end

  PRO READ_TAU_IN, TAU, INFILE=INFILE

  ...

  end

  FUNCTION READ_HRIT, slot, ChannelId, counts, pgm=pgm

  ...

  end

---

- file name 2 named "read_scenes_in.pro"

  PRO READ_SCENES_FLG, NTEST, INDIR=INDIR, INDATE=INDATE

  ...

  end

  PRO READ_SCENES_ELEV, IELEV, INDIR=INDIR

  ...

  end

  PRO READ_TAU_IN, TAU, INFILE=INFILE

  ...

  end

  FUNCTION READ_HRIT2, slot, ChannelId, counts, pgm=pgm

  ...

  end

Comment: Thanks for putting so much efforts in your question. Would like to request you that keep your question simple, could you please edit your question and simply add expected output more clearly and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
find . -name '*.pro' \
  -exec grep -Eo '(PRO|FUNCTION)[ ]+[^ ,]+' /dev/null {} +
```

where the whitespace inside both character classes  `[...]` consists of a space and a tab.

The file name separator output by `grep` is a colon; it should not be hard to change this by way of a simple `sed` postprocessing step if it's important. Or maybe switch from `grep` to Awk to have more control over how the output is generated.